# assign variable value with button android

Tags: android, onclick, addition

i have a little program. U have to insert 3 values on EditText and have a button with metod OnClick. But when i push the button (have to add some variables) my app is closing.

I dont know if the problem is some variable, but i was reading and cant do fix it.

Thats my full class:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Preguntas extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preguntas);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_preguntas, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void calculaP(){
    //Declaramos las 2 variables de cada uno de los valores
    String edadActual;
    int EdadActualFinal;
    String edadInicial;
    int edadInicialFinal;
    String mediaSemana;
    int mediaSemanaFinal;
    String Resultado;
    int ResultadoFinal;

    //Objetos de cada widget
    EditText miEdad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdadActual);
    EditText miEdadInicial = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdadInicial);
    EditText miMedia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MediaSemana);
    TextView MiResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ResultadoValor);

    //Convertimos los String por Integers
    edadActual = miEdad.getText().toString();
    EdadActualFinal = Integer.parseInt(edadActual);

    edadInicial = miEdadInicial.getText().toString();
    edadInicialFinal = Integer.parseInt(edadInicial);

    mediaSemana = miMedia.getText().toString();
    mediaSemanaFinal = Integer.parseInt(mediaSemana);

    Resultado = MiResultado.getText().toString();
    ResultadoFinal = Integer.parseInt(Resultado);

    ResultadoFinal = ((EdadActualFinal - edadInicialFinal)* (mediaSemanaFinal * 48));

    MiResultado.setText(ResultadoFinal);
```

Comment: Please post your Logcat Error @Aris

Comment: are you getting any error? post the log

Comment: Do you want convert string to integer?

Comment: @ErmineSoft with this i convert string to integer cause the information y write is numbers

Comment: where is your oncreate() method?

Comment: upside, this is only the method i call with onClick

Comment: @ArisGuimerá Hope you have used `setContentView()` inside your onCreate()?

Comment: @Droidwala added full class

Comment: @ArisGuimerá where do you call `calculaP()` method? Do you call it inside `onClick()` method?

Comment: @Droidwala on my button, i call calculaP() with onClick

https://i.gyazo.com/3eb9bef3c4702ac183091c769f3006d5.png

Comment: Ohh..well!! that's where the problem lies...you need to change the calculaP() method if you are using it inside onclick().. the code you have pasted of calculaP() is not correct

Comment: Also, can you post your `onClick()` method code?

Comment: I have not onClick method, just call calculaP() using onClick option on the button like u can see on the image.

https://i.gyazo.com/3eb9bef3c4702ac183091c769f3006d5.png

I have to create anything else?

Comment: @ArisGuimerá  I will write short answer below...just try moving those lines to onCreate() method..and see if that works!

Answer (score 0):

But here is an error

> Could not find a method calculaP(View) in the activity class
>   com.example.dam.semenapp.Preguntas for onClick handler on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'cum' 10-30
>   Android can not find your function.

Comment: Yep, i see the problem but dont know why is happend. My code is bad?

Answer (score 0):

Just try moving below lines from `CalculaP()` to inside your `onCreate()` method:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Preguntas extends AppCompatActivity {

   EditText miEdad,miEdadInicial,miMedia;
   TextView MiResultado;
   Button myButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_preguntas);
     miEdad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdadActual);
     miEdadInicial = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdadInicial);
     miMedia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MediaSemana);
     MiResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ResultadoValor);
     myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
     myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

      public void OnClick(View v){
            calculaP(); //Call your method
         }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_preguntas, menu);
      return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
   // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   int id = item.getItemId();

   //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
   if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
     }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
}

 public void calculaP(){
//Declaramos las 2 variables de cada uno de los valores
String edadActual;
int EdadActualFinal;
String edadInicial;
int edadInicialFinal;
String mediaSemana;
int mediaSemanaFinal;
String Resultado;
int ResultadoFinal;

//Objetos de cada widget
//Comment below four lines and move them to Oncreate() instead.
 /*
EditText miEdad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdadActual);
EditText miEdadInicial = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdadInicial);
EditText miMedia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MediaSemana);
TextView MiResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ResultadoValor);
   */
//Convertimos los String por Integers
edadActual = miEdad.getText().toString();
EdadActualFinal = Integer.parseInt(edadActual);

edadInicial = miEdadInicial.getText().toString();
edadInicialFinal = Integer.parseInt(edadInicial);

mediaSemana = miMedia.getText().toString();
mediaSemanaFinal = Integer.parseInt(mediaSemana);

Resultado = MiResultado.getText().toString();
ResultadoFinal = Integer.parseInt(Resultado);

ResultadoFinal = ((EdadActualFinal - edadInicialFinal)* (mediaSemanaFinal * 48));

MiResultado.setText(ResultadoFinal);
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you, but close too.



"FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 14:24:55.041 16294-16294/com.example.dam.semenapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.dam.semenapp, PID: 16294
10-31 14:24:55.041 16294-16294/com.example.dam.semenapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method calculaP(View) in the activity class com.example.dam.semenapp.Preguntas for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'myButton'  "

Comment: OK..just define button and define `onClickListener()` on it..and then inside it's `onClick()` call your method... code added..check and see if it works..

Comment: define where? i dont understand. Why i have to define button if y call my method on the button?

Comment: I am not sure..i don't use the way you have written onClick() method on button using IDE..generally i directly define it inside Activity class like above..see if that helps!!

Comment: Finally i got this!, the first problem was this 2 lines:

Resultado = MiResultado.getText().toString();
ResultadoFinal = Integer.parseInt(Resultado);

And to convert the last string (MiResultado) just have to post this ("" +) for example: MiResultado.setText( "" + ResultadoFinal);

Thanks all :)